# Rest endpoint for one to many to many

Tags: rest

Not sure how to define an endpoint for this.

Lets say my datamodel is

- Group 1toMany students
- Students 1toMany tuitionPayments
- Students 1toMany Classes

The endpoint I need will know the group id,  but wants to grab all the students in that group and for each student the list of classes and payments

The start of the end point is group and student object

GET /group/123/student/...

No student ID as I want to get a list students. I was thinking of having a parameter that lists the amount of data to return for each student but not sure how well this will work or if there is a more accepted method. due to some other factors I don't want the client to call the endpoint for each student,

GET /group/123/student?Details={classes, tuition}

Comment: `GET /groups/123/students/all/classes-and-tuition`

NB I tend to add a `/all/` if I think there's a possibility I'll want retrieval by specific ID in future. It keeps the schema nice and consistent in the event of adding that new endpoint.

Comment: ...another approach is to always use the same endpoint `/groups/123/students/` but then have the client use a custom media type in the header, to denote whether they want classes and/or tuition data. This is more full-blown "HATEOAS" REST though, which is a bit extreme and isn't often followed - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS